# как передать содержимое DIV в таблицу SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день!
Создаю блок новостей на сайте c привязкой к таблице SQL (название, дата, описание, контент). Контент нужно сохранить со всеми стилями(шрифт, цвет и прочее), чтобы в таком же виде извлекать в нужном месте.
Подскажите, как сохранить содержимое тега DIV в таблице SQL?